# Can't change background color in access

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I've attempted multiple changes to this, I'm trying to fill the background on an empty box in an access report but can't get this to do so. My eyes are exhausted and just don't see where I've gone wrong

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
On Len(Trim(Me![Text61])) = vbNullString GoTo color_box

Const WHITE = 16777215
Const GRAY = 14540253

 If (Me![LineNum] Mod 2) = 0 Then

    Me![Text60].BackColor = GRAY
    Me![bmnh].BackColor = GRAY
    Me![c_val].BackColor = GRAY
    Me![Text61].BackColor = GRAY

Else

    Me![Text60].BackColor = WHITE
    Me![c_val].BackColor = WHITE
    Me![Text61].BackColor = WHITE
    Me![bmnh].BackColor = WHITE

End If

exit_here:
    Exit Sub


color_box:
        Me![Text61].BackColor = GRAY
Resume exit_here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, you were pretty close.

```
Const WHITE = 16777215
Const GRAY = 14540253
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    If Len(Trim(Me![Text61])) = 0 Then GoTo color_box

    If (Me![LineNum] Mod 2) = 0 Then
        Me![Text60].BackColor = GRAY
        Me![bmnh].BackColor = GRAY
        Me![c_val].BackColor = GRAY
        Me![Text61].BackColor = GRAY
    Else
        Me![Text60].BackColor = WHITE
        Me![c_val].BackColor = WHITE
        Me![Text61].BackColor = WHITE
        Me![bmnh].BackColor = WHITE
    End If

exit_here:
    Exit Sub

color_box:  
    Me![Text61].BackColor = GRAY
End Sub
```